# HTML Table Build Two Menus in one TD

Tags: html, css, html-table, valign

I have a table with one row and 2 columns. I have two menus that I would like to put in 1 column. One to the top and the second to the bottom. The `valign` doesn't work, I cant figure out how to make it work, the text in the second `td` can change so if it grows the second menu should be pushed to the bottom,

Please see my current code below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td  valign="top">
          <div class="left">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
                </ul>                                     
         </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="bottom">
           <div class="left">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
              </ul>        
           </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
       <div>
       some text here
    </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: That's a table with 2 rows, and 1 column. Does it need to be in a table?

Comment: the main table has 1 row with 2 colms, no if you have any other suggestions please share, i just thought in a table it should be easier.

Comment: If you're going to use a table for layout, add `role="presentation"` to let screen readers know that it's not tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code

try to add border="1" on all table tag. `<table border ="1">` you'' figure it out

try to valign your last `<div>`

or colspan on your specified `<td>`

[image]

new updated with this code will makes:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
     <td>
      <table border ="1">
       <tr>
        <td  valign="top">
          <div class="left">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
                </ul>                                     
         </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="bottom">
           <div class="left">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
              </ul>        
           </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div>
       some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here 
        </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: i am sorry, not really understanding what I should do, valign my last div? or colspan on specified td? could you please modify the code i posted, thx in advanced.

Comment: another way,may you put the mock up picture that you wanted?

Comment: the code that you posted is the same as mine, except for border=1, i think you forgot to put the changes, thx

Comment: try placing lots of text inside last td instead of "some text here" and you will see what i mean,. thanks

Comment: <td valign="bottom"> and <table border="1"> added

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16121/discussion-between-josua-marcel-chrisano-and-ben)

Comment: sorry didn't see your chat, I replied in the chat and provided an example of what I am trying to do, thanks for your help.